# Responsive table with equal width and height TDs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I create a responsive HTML table that each cell/TD has equal width and height? So when I resize the browser window or resize the table's container, the table will resize, but each cell will have equal height and width.

Foundation doesn't take care of that. When I initialize the TD with fixed width and height in pixels, when resize the width of the browser, it shrinks the td horizontally, but doesn't keep the same aspect ratio.

I am using Foundation as my my base responsive framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is a way of doing it that will work .

https://jsfiddle.net/ocp36uLb/32/

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

By setting the padding to be the same as the width we create a square that maintains it's aspect ratio on resize. We also need to use `display: inline-block;` to override the default `display: table-cell;` which will make a cell expand to fit it's parent table. `border-collapse: collapse;` is also important as it overrides any table related border rendering.

However, this method may well be a pixel out at some sizes due to the way tables render. It [works perfectly for divs](https://jsfiddle.net/ocp36uLb/13/) (which you could use instead, I'm guessing) - even without the border-collapse definition.

Another way which will work perfectly for tables is to [use `vw` units](https://jsfiddle.net/ocp36uLb/31/). A bit more complex as they take there size from the viewport, so you'll need to consider what proportion of the viewport your overall table size is. `1vw` is 1% of the viewport. You'll see from the link that it's perfect.

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    height: 15vw;
    width: 15vw;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

vw units are [not so well supported yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw) (old IEs, some mobile browsers) so it would probably be worth using a fallback.

Comment: what if you have more than two cells, for example 8 cells. I did 12.5% for the width and padding-bottom but when I resized the height and width are not equal.

Comment: @IdanShechter - https://jsfiddle.net/ocp36uLb/2/ - did you also add eight cells to each row?

Comment: yes, 8x8. This https://jsfiddle.net/ocp36uLb/4/  yields 35x37 pixel TDs when I resize

Comment: looks like a quirk of tables (funny things) these divs behave: https://jsfiddle.net/ocp36uLb/13/ - a reset may be required, or some offset of width and padding, I'll look into this shortly and edit my answer

Comment: off the record, is there an option to make the cells size maintain the same height and width when text added. When I add text or other content it expands the cell height.

Answer (score 0):

That works well if you have no content in the `<td>`. But with some content the padding is extra to the height of the content. see example below:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 100%; background-color: #896464">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 100%; background-color: #20A034">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```