# Table formatting - how to get consistent/equivalent sizes?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table, always three columns of relatively the same info.

I'm trying to get it to look like this:
[image]

So, each "cell" (in the `x` area) is currently two `td`'s, one for the text and other for the image.

I'm trying to figure out how to evenly space them all across the page *and* put a small margin in between each one.

Currently, it looks like this[image]

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width:33%">
            <col style="width:33%">
            <col style="width:33%">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellData">
                    <h2><u>Brennon Huels</u></h2>
                    <p id="email">Meghan35@hotmail.com</p>
                    <p id="phoneNumber">279-027-8862 x78041</p>
                </td>
                <td class="cellImage">
                    <img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg >
                </td>

                <td class="cellData">
                    <h2><u>Xzavier Schinner</u></h2>
                    <p id="email">Ayla_Fritsch@hotmail.com</p>
                    <p id="phoneNumber">078-723-5610 x715</p>
                </td>
                <td class="cellImage">
                    <img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg >
                </td>

                <td class="cellData">
                    <h2><u>Leone Mayert</u></h2>
                    <p id="email">Nicolette.Nicolas@yahoo.com</p>
                    <p id="phoneNumber">003-101-8397</p>
                </td>
                <td class="cellImage">
                    <img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg >
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td class="cellData">
                    <h2><u>Moriah Howe</u></h2>
                    <p id="email">Carli_Friesen7@hotmail.com</p>
                    <p id="phoneNumber">1-837-151-2364 x2091</p>
                </td>
                <td class="cellImage">
                    <img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg >
                </td>

                <td class="cellData">
                    <h2><u>Jayce Koch</u></h2>
                    <p id="email">Joaquin.Barrows@hotmail.com</p>
                    <p id="phoneNumber">1-227-294-3980 x9561</p>
                </td>
                <td class="cellImage">
                    <img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg >
                </td>

                <td class="cellData">
                    <h2><u>Mekhi Haag</u></h2>
                    <p id="email">Neva3@hotmail.com</p>
                    <p id="phoneNumber">(682) 411-5607 x6897</p>
                </td>
                <td class="cellImage">
                    <img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellData">
                    <h2><u>Merl Kshlerin</u></h2>
                    <p id="email">Harold_Deckow@yahoo.com</p>
                    <p id="phoneNumber">627-951-5298 x726</p>
                </td>
                <td class="cellImage">
                    <img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg >
                </td>               
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

tr{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

table td{
    border:3px solid red;
    width:33%;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

tr td{
    margin: 10px;
    width: 33%;
}

td img{
    /*display: block;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 4px;
}

tr p{
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

I've tried playing with the classes to no avail, and tried applying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762478/responsive-table-with-equal-width-and-height-tds) but also didn't work, so I'm stuck.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: if a table is the wrong way to go, I'm open to alternatives...I'm  still learning html so just did a table because since I wanted something that looks like it, but no other reason.

Comment: This should not be using tables to begin with ... you have a _list_ of items here, so you should start by writing proper markup.

Comment: @CBroe is right.  You should use proper markup.  Table is for tabular data.  However, if you absolutely must use tables, then here is one of the solutions: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZJbyo.  Hope this helps!

Comment: @CBroe ah! Ok yeah I just used tables because ....well no reason. I can absolutely use something else like a list. ...will have to think about that and how to format it

Comment: @CBroe - I looked around online, but am trying to see why a list is preferable (or when to use a table instead).  That's not to say you're incorrect, it's just in my mind I'd think a table? But you're definitely correct I have a list of items...so I tried, but ended up posting a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553878/horizontal-list-formatting-separate-ul-from-image) where I tried to use lists, and one answer posted uses a table.  Do I want to have a table wrapped around the lists?  Thanks for any direction or advice!