# Horizontal list formatting - separate ul from image

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to get a horizontal list formatted so the image is on the left side of the `ul`.  Here's an idea of what I'm aiming for (green is the image, the `x`,`y`,`z` labels are to help refer to portions of each part if it helps):

[image]

But I can't seem to figure out how to keep my image 'separate' from the text part of the `ul`.

HTML:

```
<span class='row'>
    <ul class = 'top-ul'>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><h2><u>Colby Abbott</u></h2></li><br>
            <li><p id="email">Enos.Goyette@hotmail.com</p></li><br>
            <li><p id="phoneNumber">360.751.0915</p></li>
            <li><img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg ></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><h2><u>Jamaal Powlowski</u></h2></li><br>
            <li><p id="email">Stan.Roberts48@gmail.com</p></li><br>
            <li><p id="phoneNumber">(057) 629-2042 x2604</p></li>
            <li><img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg ></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><h2><u>Ubaldo Bode</u></h2></li><br>
            <li><p id="email">Alia.Lynch52@gmail.com</p></li><br>
            <li><p id="phoneNumber">881.886.7822 x87177</p></li>
            <li><img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg ></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><h2><u>Herbert Bailey</u></h2></li><br>
            <li><p id="email">Arnaldo73@gmail.com</p></li><br>
            <li><p id="phoneNumber">1-620-830-6732</p></li>
            <li><img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg ></li>
        </ul>

    </ul>
    <br>
</span>
<span class='row'>
    <ul>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><h2><u>Alana Legros</u></h2></li><br>
            <li><p id="email">John.Nienow37@hotmail.com</p></li><br>
            <li><p id="phoneNumber">299.276.2872 x90430</p></li>
            <li><img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg ></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><h2><u>Gertrude Jacobs</u></h2></li><br>
            <li><p id="email">Erna_Krajcik94@gmail.com</p></li><br>
            <li><p id="phoneNumber">(335) 097-2437</p></li>
            <li><img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg ></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><h2><u>Ellis Homenick</u></h2></li><br>
            <li><p id="email">Ezra_Stamm76@yahoo.com</p></li><br>
            <li><p id="phoneNumber">(391) 333-5140</p></li>
            <li><img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg ></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    width:100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

ul ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border: 3px red solid;
    width:20%;
}


li img{ /* I want to move this to the right of the ul it's in somehow */
    display: inline;
    border: 3px solid green;
}


p {
    margin:0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.row{
    width: 100%;
}

.row li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

But it turns out [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgLYK.jpg).

How could I 'break apart' the image, so the text stays center (or top) aligned, with the image to the right; while also having the border be tighter around each `ul`?

Edit: I'm new to html/css, so if there's a better way to format this generally, please let me know. Per below, it was mentioned to use a list to do this ...so the above is my attempt but it's likely I'm not thinking of something else that'd be better.

<sub>FWIW, I tried doing this as a table, but [was recommended to use a list instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513249/table-formatting-how-to-get-consistent-equivalent-sizes)</sub>

Comment: Have you tried using a table layout for this?

Comment: Be aware that IDs must be unique in a web page; <ul> should not contain an <ul> directly; <span> should not contain an <ul>; <br> should not be sibling of <li>; src= value should be quoted; please use semantic and valid markup.

Comment: @Stickers - re: id's, d'oh! I knew that.  I'm actually 'generating' the HTML via node.js/express, so it's looping through a JS object and creating a UL. Didn't catch that I had an ID in there, good point.  I did a `ul` within `ul` because I can't quite figure otherwise how to generate the lists like I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on using your semantics, this is the solution I can come up with with the least possible changes in your code.

### HTML

> ```
> <ul class="menu"> #change id to class
>     <li> #placed all the info you want on the left to a single li element
>       <h2><u>Colby Abbott</u></h2>
>       <p id="email">Enos.Goyette@hotmail.com</p>
>       <p id="phoneNumber">360.751.0915</p>
>     </li>
>     <li> #right side
>       <img src=https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg >
>     </li>
> </ul>
> ```

### CSS

> ```
> ul.menu {
>   border: 3px red solid;
>   width: 400px;
> }
>
> ul.menu li {
>   list-style-type: none;
>   margin: 0;
>   padding: 0;
>   overflow: hidden;
>   float:left;
> }
>
>
> ul.menu li img{
>   display: inline;
>   border: 3px solid green;
>   float: right;
>   width: 100px;
> }
> ```

Then repeat this for all your sections.

Side note: I also removed the `<br>`s at the end of your `li` elements because they're unnecessary. I highly suggest reading up on [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) because it does exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't insist on using them. Per my link to the other post, it was suggested to use a list ...so that is my attempt. If there's a better way to set it up, I'm all ears!

Comment: I tried this, but it all ended up [super funky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jnI7.jpg). (Note I only used the css you posted, if that matters).

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. You're supposed to add the CSS I posted. [Here](https://codepen.io/reiallenramos/pen/yvNrbm). I'll leave the formatting of the left side details to you.

Comment: Ah! It's so close!  The only thing is I'd like to push the image to the right of the `ul`.  See how currently isn't almost centered? How do I move it to the right side of the `ul` (still in the `ul`, but more to the right)?